# Coldfusion cfpdf thumbnail plus preview?

Tags: coldfusion, cfpdf

we have a great deal of PDF content on our site. I have some perfectly usable CFPDF thumbnails generated from Page 1 of each PDF. I thought it would be nice to have the thumbnail jpg be a link such that when you click it, you either see the first page as is, or another preview at full scale is generated.

I am experimenting with using CFPDF's merge action, but without much luck so far. There does not seem to be a way to just extract a single page from the PDF -- only delete them.

Does anybody have any suggestions? I really do appreciate it! Thanks!

UPDATE: to try and clarify, here's the code I am using right now. Sorry for the confusion!

```
<cfset dir = expandPath("\images\thumbs")>
<cfif not directoryExists(dir)>
    <cfdirectory action="create" directory="#dir#">
</cfif>
<cfset firstPage = expandPath("\images\thumbs\firstPage.pdf")>

<cfpdf action="thumbnail"
source="source"
destination="#dir#" 
format="jpg" 
scale="40"
overwrite="yes"
pages="1" 
resolution="low">
<cfpdf action="merge"
source="sameSource"
pages="1"
destination="#firstPage#"
overwrite="yes">
<a href="firstPage.pdf" target="_blank"> 
<img src="thumbnail.jpg" style="border: 1px solid silver;">
</a>
```

Anyways I hope that explains better what I am trying to do. Like I said, this works, but firstPage.pdf is always just the one file -- what happens if several people are previewing different PDFs at the same time, for example?

Thanks!

Comment: I forgot to mention that currently I am generating two thumbnails, one at full scale and one smaller, and am linking to the big one from the little one. It's workable but clunky and even the "full scale" preview isn't. Thanks!

Comment: The question is a little unclear ;) Are you asking how to extract an arbitrary page or create a thumbnail image of an arbitrary page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(If I am understanding the question correctly ...)

Sure you can use merge to extract a single page:

```
<cfpdf action = "merge" 
    source="c:\dev\myFile.pdf"
    pages="10"
    name="singlePage" />

<cfcontent type="application/pdf" variable="#ToBinary(singlePage)#">
```

> what happens if several people are previewing different PDFs at the
>   same time, for example?

**Edit:** Some of them will end up previewing the *wrong* page and/or thumbnail image ;) To avoid that, you must generate a unique file name each time, such as using [getTempFile()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7c60.html), [createUUID()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-70de.html) &".pdf", etcetera.

Though technically you do not have to create a file. You can generate images/pdfs in memory only and serve them with cfcontent (like in the example above).

Comment: I've got it working, but I am not sure if it's "proper" or not. I added this <cfset firstPage = expandPath("\images\thumbs\firstPage.pdf")> before merging with CFPDF to #firstPage*. Then I set the target of the thumbnail link to this file. It seems to work, and a new PDF is generated with each different file that I click on, but, well... something is bothering me, lol. I do not know enough about this to tell what it might be. Any ideas? And thanks again for your help, Leigh, I appreciate it!

Comment: Thanks Leigh, I am working on that right now. I am having trouble figuring out how to tie the in-memory PDFs to the thumbnail link, though, such that when you click on the thumbnail, *then* it serves the cfcontent file. I tried making the img src a separate cfm, itself containing the cfcontent, but I am getting an "undefined" error. Any clues?

Comment: Okay I think I got it working using createUUID(). Several files are being created now, and Page One of each PDF is opening in the browser like they should. Thanks a lot! I really appreciate your help, I think this will work fine. Of course, now I need to figure out how to delete all of those files, lol! But hey one thing at a time. Thanks again Leigh I appreciate it!

Comment: One option is to place them in the cf temp directory so they are removed automatically. Re: The in memory method, the `<img src...>` would still be the thumbnail image. But you would open the .cfm script (containing the cfpdf merge and cfcontent code) on click. ie Just like your original link behaves.

Comment: Hi Leigh, thanks for the update! Sorry it has taken me so long to reply. I added the merge code and some other stuff to the cfm and it is working great, just like you said. Many thanks for your patience and help! I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

Its very easy

```
<cfpdf source="pdfdata" pages="1" action="thumbnail" destination="." format="jpg" overwrite="true" resolution="high" scale="25">
```

That will turn page one into a jpg

Comment: Thanks Dale, I am pretty clear on that part -- the thumbnail JPGs look fine, and the scale="100" JPGs don't look too bad either. But what I'd like is to have the thumbnail be a link to the full-on first page of the PDF itself -- not another thumbnail (which is what I am doing now). Thanks a lot though!

Comment: That should be easy, just a `<a href` around the image and your set.